# Sorting ObservableCollection to DataGrid does work correctly for first run

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The solution to this must be very simple and just missing it.

I have a DataGrid that is being bound to an ObservableCollection.  This ObservableCollection must be group and sorted.  I am doing it like this;

```
ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group1"));
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group2"));
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group3"));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group1", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group2", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group3", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Yet if it is re-run it works.  So its only the first time.  I can get around it by doing this;

```
ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group1"));
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group2"));
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group3"));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group1", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group2", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group3", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
collection = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group1"));
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group2"));
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group3"));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group1", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group2", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Group3", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
```

That just seems stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
// consider this:
// ObservableCollection<...> myCollection = ...
// then
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group1"));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Group1", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```

Your datasource will remain the same, only the 'view' is modified.

Your code is not working because you actually set the datasource directly to ListCollectionView but
WPF creates another view which wraps your ListCollectionView collection. So you have to call CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView to get the actually binded view.